# Multi inheritance from templated classes

Tags: c++

I was trying to do some practical work, and was thinking to do something like this but couldn't find any solution to it, how to run this program? (note: this is just a theory or say abstract practical nothing to do with real world relationships)

```
template<typename T> class animal
{
public:
    T data;
    animal():data(T()) {}
};

template<typename Foo> class amph
{
    Foo fooo;
public:
    amph():fooo(Foo()) {}
};

template<typename T>
template<typename Foo>
class lion : public animal<T> ,public amph<Foo> // error: too many template-parameter-lists
{
    std::string name;
public:
    lion():name(std::string()) {}
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    animal<std::string> notGoodAnimal;
     lion<int><int> mylion;// this line is probelm
}
```

So how can we run this?, thanks 0_o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename T, typename Foo>
class lion : public animal<T> ,public amph<Foo>
...

lion<int, int> mylion;
```